# Android cordova download option is not working after exporting the android application

Tags: android, cordova, download, cordova-plugins

I am trying to build the android app with cordova. I have download feature in that app. After adding necessary plugins when I am running the application download is working fine. But After exporting the application download is not working. Please see my error log.

```
 12-07 14:06:56.539: W/System.err(1731): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils
    12-07 14:06:56.539: W/System.err(1731):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    12-07 14:06:56.543: W/System.err(1731):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
    12-07 14:06:56.543: W/System.err(1731):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
    12-07 14:06:56.547: W/System.err(1731):     at a.a.a.bc.c(Unknown Source)
    12-07 14:06:56.547: W/System.err(1731):     at a.a.a.bc.a(Unknown Source)
    12-07 14:06:56.547: W/System.err(1731):     at a.a.a.bc.b(Unknown Source)
    12-07 14:06:56.551: W/System.err(1731):     at a.a.a.bc.a(Unknown Source)
    12-07 14:06:56.551: W/System.err(1731):     at a.a.a.ae.a(Unknown Source)
    12-07 14:06:56.555: W/System.err(1731):     at a.a.a.ae.a(Unknown Source)
    12-07 14:06:56.555: W/System.err(1731):     at a.a.a.ae.loadUrl(Unknown Source)
    12-07 14:06:56.555: W/System.err(1731):     at a.a.a.e.a(Unknown Source)
    12-07 14:06:56.559: W/System.err(1731):     at com.super.navya.navya.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    12-07 14:06:56.559: W/System.err(1731):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    12-07 14:06:56.563: W/System.err(1731):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    12-07 14:06:56.563: W/System.err(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
    12-07 14:06:56.567: W/System.err(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
    12-07 14:06:56.567: W/System.err(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    12-07 14:06:56.567: W/System.err(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    12-07 14:06:56.567: W/System.err(1731):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    12-07 14:06:56.567: W/System.err(1731):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    12-07 14:06:56.567: W/System.err(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    12-07 14:06:56.567: W/System.err(1731):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-07 14:06:56.567: W/System.err(1731):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    12-07 14:06:56.567: W/System.err(1731):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    12-07 14:06:56.567: W/System.err(1731):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    12-07 14:06:56.571: W/System.err(1731):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    12-07 14:06:56.571: W/System.err(1731): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cordova/file/FileUtils
    12-07 14:06:56.571: W/System.err(1731):     ... 26 more
    12-07 14:06:56.571: W/System.err(1731): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.super.navya-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.super.navya-1, /system/lib]]
    12-07 14:06:56.575: W/System.err(1731):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    12-07 14:06:56.575: W/System.err(1731):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
    12-07 14:06:56.575: W/System.err(1731):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
    12-07 14:06:56.575: W/System.err(1731):     ... 26 more
    12-07 14:06:56.575: I/System.out(1731): Error adding plugin org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils.
    12-07 14:06:56.575: D/AndroidRuntime(1731): Shutting down VM
    12-07 14:06:56.579: W/dalvikvm(1731): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d33b20)
    12-07 14:06:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1731): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    12-07 14:06:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1731): Process: com.super.navya, PID: 1731
    12-07 14:06:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1731): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.super.navya/com.super.navya.navya}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    12-07 14:06:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
    12-07 14:06:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
    12-07 14:06:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    12-07 14:06:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    12-07 14:06:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    12-07 14:06:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    12-07 14:06:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    12-07 14:06:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-07 14:06:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    12-07 14:06:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    12-07 14:06:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    12-07 14:06:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    12-07 14:06:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1731): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    12-07 14:06:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at a.a.a.bc.a(Unknown Source)
    12-07 14:06:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at a.a.a.bc.b(Unknown Source)
    12-07 14:06:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at a.a.a.bc.a(Unknown Source)
    12-07 14:06:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at a.a.a.ae.a(Unknown Source)
    12-07 14:06:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at a.a.a.ae.a(Unknown Source)
    12-07 14:06:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at a.a.a.ae.loadUrl(Unknown Source)
    12-07 14:06:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at a.a.a.e.a(Unknown Source)
    12-07 14:06:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at com.super.navya.navya.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    12-07 14:06:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    12-07 14:06:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    12-07 14:06:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
    12-07 14:06:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you didn´t add the file system plugin, as seen on the first line of you error log:

12-07 14:06:56.539: W/System.err(1731): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils

You might also be using some outdated code, incompatible with your version of Apache Cordova.

I would recommend this plugin: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file-transfer

Comment: Hi @Giordano Thanks for answer. But My biggest concern is when I run the app to debug the download option is working. But after exporting only I am facing this issue. Please clarify this.

Comment: Did you install the FileUtils plugin?